# Sails.js How to add the src/href by the vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, sails.js

```html
<img src="{{ event.imageurl }}" alt="Placeholder image" />

<a class="title is-4" href="http://localhost:1337/detail/{{ event.id }}">{{ event.eventname }}</a>
```

`event.imageurl` and the `<a>` link is not able to show. But the other elements without link are correct to show on

**Error in image and link**

`http://localhost:1337/detail/%7B%7B%20event.id%20%7D%7D`

[error of link of `<a>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbQFf.png)

Even I add `:` before `src/href`, it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I know how to solve it

```
<img :src="event.imageurl" alt="Placeholder image" />
<a class="title is-4" :href="'http://localhost:1337/detail/'+ event.id ">{{ event.eventname }}</a >
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `:` before `src`/`href`, and then remove `{{}}`